# What I'm going to do is, I'm going to ask you about this sentence form

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology

Is there a name for sentence forms that tell you that they’re about to tell you something? For example:

> “*What he did was*, he went to the bus stop to meet his friend.”
>
> “*What she’s doing is*, she’s priming the canvas with gesso.”
>
> “*What I’ll do is*, I’ll call you if I’m running late.”

These sentences could be described as “unnecessarily wordy” or maybe “circuitous”, but is there a technical, grammatical term for these sentence forms? If not, then is there a term for the italicized phrases?